# How do I palindrome this String in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

One of my statements still doesn't return true. I have this for my code:

```
    function palindrome(str) {



 str = str.replace(/[ ,\.]/g,'').toLowerCase();
 if (str===str.split('').reverse().join('')) {

return true;}
  else  {
    return false;


  }

}

palindrome("eye");
```

This is the one that's not returning true:
palindrome("0_0 (: /-\ :) 0-0") should return true.

Comment: isn't 'eye' a palindrome?

Comment: Yeah, sorry that is apart of the code it just didn't format with it

Comment: so if a string is palindrome, your function should return false?

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo, but your example isn't a palindrome? _ on the left and - on the right

Answer (score 1):

str.replace returns a value but it is not set back to str.

```
str = str.replace(/[ ,\.]/g, '').toLowerCase();
```

Comment: One of my statements is not becoming true still. Right now I have this for my code:

Comment: function palindrome(str) {

 str = str.replace(/[ ,\.]/g,'').toLowerCase();
 if (str===str.split('').reverse().join('')) {

return true;}
  else  {
    return false;
  

  }

}



palindrome("eye");